# MS Access Append Query, no error message, no result, no known cause

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

Here goes with as much detail and clarity as I can give you...

**Goal:** Append portions of "Validated" table to several existing tables, all related by "PropertyID" field

**Problem:** Even a very basic append query fails to work. I created a query in design view to append [PropertyName] from the Validated table to the GeneralProperty table. Both are text field, same length, not required, allowed zero length, not indexed. When I run the query nothing happens. No error message, no result. The GeneralProperty table remains empty. I went to SQL view and pressed run on the following query and still got nothing:

```
INSERT INTO GeneralProperty ( PropertyName )
SELECT [Import2-Validated].PropertyName
FROM [Import2-Validated];
```

**Additional Info:**

- Primary Key is "PropertyID" and it is an *autonumbered* field.
- GeneralProperty table contains the above Primary key
- Four other tables contain "PropertyID", joined by a relationship
- Relationship enforces referential integrity, and cascades updates+deletes
- Append query **does work** to append text from the "Validated" table to tables *other* than GeneralProperty, so long as I do *not* try to append PropertyID in the query.
- Database is working as expected for manual entry through a form. All relationships and autonumbering of the primary key work as expected.

Using MS Access 2010

**Edits**

1. Result of `SELECT [Import2-Validated].PropertyName` is a popup to enter parameter value
2. Haven't specified `DoCmd.SetWarnings=False` in code anywhere

Comment: What is your result if you run "SELECT [Import2-Validated].PropertyName" on it's own?

Comment: Have you accidentally left `DoCmd.SetWarnings = false` somewhere? (it should be `true`)

Comment: `Result of SELECT [Import2-Validated].PropertyName is a popup to enter parameter value` This means that the PropertyName is not a field in the [Import2-Validated] table